# Using Exchange server as a bridge with APIs?

Tags: api, exchange-server

does anyone know if it's possible to use Exchange server as a bridge with APIs ?

In my company, we have some APIs (like mail, contact, calendar ...). 
We are searching a solution to synchronize contacts and calendars from our APIs on smartphones (without any optional application).

For example, I add an Exchange account into an iPhone. I choose to synchronize my contacts. We want the Exchange server to query our contact API which will return a Json encoded response. Through a Exchange plugin, we could transform this response to match with the Exchange format.

We didn't want to store any datas into the Exchange server to avoid redundancy.

Does someone think that there is a solution to do this ? (I saw that there are 2 or 3 SDK for Exchange but I didn't find some informations about what I'm searching. Otherwise, I'm not an expert in Microsoft Exchange :/ )

Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that.
Exchange will not be calling you, it is your responsibility to call Exchange to request existing data or create new items in one of the Exchange mailboxes.